# Select MAX() of Multiple Columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I currently have a massive query (using PHP and MySQL) and I'm not sure how to optimize it in order to reduce its massive load of 18-25 seconds. I've looked at previous answers and have found that they all sort of write a similarly large amount of code resulting in a similar script execution time and so I'd like to see if anyone would have any alternative ideas as opposed to the ones already posed:

**TLDR;** I need to select the maximum column for each analytics ID and this takes on a massive load and so i need to reduce it somehow

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ip,country_code,country,
(SELECT MAX(region)  FROM analytics RegOne WHERE bid='$id' AND RegOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS region,
(SELECT MAX(city)    FROM analytics CitOne WHERE bid='$id' AND CitOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS city,
(SELECT MAX(os)      FROM analytics OSOne  WHERE bid='$id' AND OSOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS os,
(SELECT MIN(browser) FROM analytics BroOne WHERE bid='$id' AND BroOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS browser,
(SELECT MIN(resolution) FROM analytics ResOne  WHERE bid='$id' AND ResOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS resolution,
(SELECT MAX(timestamp)  FROM analytics DateOne WHERE bid='$id' AND DateOne.ip= IPOne.ip) AS LatestDate
FROM analytics AS IPOne
WHERE bid='$id'
ORDER BY LatestDate DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET $offset";
```

This is taking data from a massive table and so i don't expect it to take 0 seconds however any time reduction would be fine rather than ~21 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a composite KEY on `(bid, ip)`.
If you have KEY on `(bid)` then add (or replace it with) `(bid, ip)`

Comment: I simply indexed them instead; it didn't let me make both of them a primary key/composite key for some reason, however thank you! Indexing seemed to work like a charm

Comment: @Josh "key" and "index" mean the same thing in MySQL. You can only have one primary key, you can have as many other keys as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
SELECT ip, country_code, country,
     MAX(region) as region,
     MAX...
     MAX(timestamp) as LatestDate
FROM analytics
WHERE bid = '$id'
GROUP BY ip, country_code, country
ORDER BY LatestDate DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET $offset";
```

You should have some index starting with `bid`.  This might be better:

```
INDEX(bid, ip, country_code, country)
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. Avoiding the correlated subqueries in the SELECT list will usually give better performance.